# Is there a limit to the integer size representing a native token supply?

Tags: native-assets

Is there a limit to the integer size representing a native token supply in  Plutus? Does it share the same limit as Haskell GHC's native `Integer` representation of ~16GB (if I am not wrong). Does Plutus also use the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types#Nomenclature-and-Types) library for token supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native tokens supplies are indeed unbounded integers. While the current implementation relies on GHC native Integers, the practical limit is much lower since it needs to fit in a transaction for which there's a maximum size of a few kilobytes.

Comment: "it needs to fit in a transaction" -- Depending on your minting policy, you could create tokens in multiple transactions. There is a max in a single transaction, but I don't know if there is a limit to he number of transactions that create that token.

Comment: That is correct, but, if you wanted to group those tokens into one UTXO, the output would need to fit in a transaction. Still, you're right, in a system doing some aggregation across the entire set, the number could be arbitrarily large.